# Live555 WebRtc integration

Tags: c++, webrtc, live555

I worked in the past on WebRTC with a C server (Janus) that i know very very well, now i want to add the WebRtc capacity to Live555 to be able to stream some video through it. 
The problem is that i'am kind of overwhelmed with the lack of documentation in live555 (worst than Janus)
If i can resume live555 lacks :

1- A SDP parser/builder

2- A HTTP signaling Parser/Builder

My question is if i see all that is missing, or need to be done ?

If by any chance someone can give me some hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Live555 make a demo that is available on http://webrtc.live555.com/, but this seems still not available opensource.

You can have a look to one of my experimentation that is available on github [webrtc-streamer](https://github.com/mpromonet/webrtc-streamer). This application use live555 as an RTSP consumer and give access to WebRTC using a embedded HTTP server (like janus-gateway does). The signaling try to be as simple as possible.

[Live Demo](https://webrtc-streamer.herokuapp.com)

Comment: I just read your code i basically understood how you manage to accomplish it (not in every details of course) and i was wondering if you could help me on a point. I want to turn your webrtc server into a streaming server. I have all the ffmpeg, encode/decode code ready for use from inside live555. But inside the webrtc server, where should i hit ? Any clue would be much appreciated. (If i manage to do it and you want the feature i ll present the code to you of course)

Comment: @HakeemElBakka-lee: better to discuss this on github. Anyway I am not sure to understand what you want try to do, a gateway webrtc -> RTSP ?

Comment: Yes, i ll contact you on GitHub, i think i ll be able to specify my idea more easily. Thank you for your time.